# how to edit run.sh file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to edit run.sh file in eclipse in windows. I'm following instructions in [here](https://github.com/nelenkov/virtual-pki-card), and I've installed the Android app completely and it's OK on my Xperia, however when it comes to building the host client part in the fourth line I don't know what run.sh does neither I know how to edit it,by the way, I guess it's a Linux file. And I have to say that I haven't installed CyanogenMod software as it is not Xperia p compatible according to it's website. The code in run.sh file in se.pki.client package, which I downloaded and imported previously, is as following.Althoug I've changed the code in the second line(giving it the path where my jdk is stored) while there's still an error in the first line saying the word "sh" is not correctly spelled and another error in the third line to

```
#!/bin/sh

JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.7.0\   
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=/usr/local/lib/libpcsclite.so -cp bin/ org.nick.sepkiclient.Main $*
```

Answer (score 0):

.sh files are the linux equivalent to a batch file. From the code you posted it just runs the java command (giving it a bunch of command line inputs) you should be able to run the same command in the windows terminal by just replacing the paths to windows paths. If there is more to the script than the 3 lines, you're going to needed to try and convert each line to a valid windows command (depending on the complexity of the script, this may not be possible.)

Your other option is to install software like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) which adds a POSIX compliment shell (along with many other linux-ish modifications). This should allow you to run .sh files 'natively' in windows (it will require some fiddling with the script to provide the correct paths). Be sure you read about cigwin before you install it, it changes quite a lot about your system that you might not be comfortable with.

Each option has its drawbacks, and both require a little knowledge of shell scripting. Might just be easier to run Linux for what your doing (it behaves itself reasonably well in a VM).

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer.Actually I'd done what you said before I posted my question with second line of the code and it worked.My problem is firstly,I don't know where the .batch file is located in windows and secondly, which file the third line is referring to.I'll appreciate it if you could help me with these.By the way,these lines hold the whole code.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'where the .batch file is located' if this is the whole script, you wont even need to write a batch file, just run the single java command.

Comment: For the paths, it gets a bit tricky, because windows and linux filesystem patterns don't match. Looking at the [Java man page](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/java.html), the -D option seems to be loading a library path into a variable...i would try to find the appropriate .dll that matches. -cp denotes the $PATH, this shouldn't be required (even on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have it set as a unix file.

Window> Preferences>General>Workspace

Select line delimiter Other then Unix and test file encoding as UTF-8

As a last resort run dos2unix on the file from the shell.